# missing some entries in a type of one specific elastic search index

Tags: elasticsearch

there was a Mysql table "user" include 12038 rows, our team have made an elastic search index for it to  enhance the search functionality of user.
there are 12039 rows in table "user" so we create 12039 entries into /test01_user/org for each row, if access the url below:

```
domain.example:9200/test01_user/org/_count
```

I got this result

```
"{"count":12039,"_shards":{"total":4,"successful":4,"failed":0}}".
```

but when I acess the same url again

```
"example:9200/test01_user/org/_count"
```

OMG, the result is

"{"count":11036,"_shards":{"total":4,"successful":4,"failed":0}}"

every time, the result is different, 12039 or 11036. I check to log file,no any modification was made on "test01_user/org".
so after I have tried several times to access the same url, I got the result below:

```
{"count":12039,"_shards":{"total":4,"successful":4,"failed":0}}
{"count":11036,"_shards":{"total":4,"successful":4,"failed":0}}
{"count":12039,"_shards":{"total":4,"successful":4,"failed":0}}
{"count":11036,"_shards":{"total":4,"successful":4,"failed":0}}
{"count":12039,"_shards":{"total":4,"successful":4,"failed":0}}
```

it seems the number of entries was 11036(why not 12039) in half of my try.
I checked the es log file trying to find something, but noting there is.

but at the next day morning after I found this problem, I got the right result:

```
{"count":12039,"_shards":{"total":4,"successful":4,"failed":0}}
{"count":12039,"_shards":{"total":4,"successful":4,"failed":0}}
{"count":12039,"_shards":{"total":4,"successful":4,"failed":0}}
{"count":12039,"_shards":{"total":4,"successful":4,"failed":0}}
```

so I can't reproduce this problem now! is there someone have meet this problem.

Comment: What does: `GET /test01/_settings?pretty` give you? Have you changed the `refresh_interval`?

Comment: Also, what version of ES are you running, and is there anything in the logs of either machine about too many open files?

Comment: here is the result of GET /test01/_settings?pretty



    `{
  "test01_user" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index.number_of_replicas" : "1",
      "index.number_of_shards" : "4",
      "index.version.created" : "190899"
    }
  }
    }`